# Emesene does not support RTL languages?

Tags: emesene, rtl

I am using Emesene 2.11.5 in Natty. But Emesene doesn't log conversations. Also right to left languages "Arabic" is written from left to right, LTR instead of RTL.

Any idea if there is a newer version that can do that? Or maybe there is something I can do to solve these problems?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can see the chat History by **right-clicking** on any user and chose **View Information**, You'll find the tab **Chat History** : 
[image]

**If you can't see logs, make sure this enabled:**

[image]

---

**For the Arabic Language:**

1.You need to Install the Arabic Language pack from the **Language Support Application**.

[image]

2.Then , you will need to go the keyboard ---> Layouts , to add the Arabic layout.

[image]

3.Switch the languages:

[image]

4.Now you can write easily right to left:

[image]

---

Edited: **From your edit, that is a design issue and we can't do anything about it:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help.But my problem as in the above picture. Help me. thx

Comment: @Bakhtiyar : It appears that you can write from right to left as the picture above, but it seems that it is a design issue that when you speak the sayings goes from the left to the right.  And for the logs chat history is the logs and it is working fine as in your picture.